# Should I uninstall WSL2 before upgrading from Windows 10 Home to Pro

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, wsl2

I have a Win 10 home with WSL2 installed with Ubuntu 20.04. Now I wish to upgrade to Win 10 Pro. Will this automatically repatriate the space taken up by WSL2/Ubuntu, since I understand it has this capability native. My concern is loss of disk space.

Comment: How did you install WSL on the Home license? "Native" just means you won't have to use work-arounds to get it to work. Worst case is that the upgrade process removes WSL itself, meaning you don't have to uninstall it.

Comment: Windows 10 Home supports WSL2.  Windows 10 Professional supports it.  Why would you need to uninstall it to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional from Windows 10 Home?

Comment: @ramhound: it wasn't clear to me if "native" in pro used some mechanism other than WSL2 for same objective; and in my experience, there are quite a number of things that seem very logical but simply are not so due to some very obscure technical nuances

Comment: WSL2 is fully documented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - I don't believe that there will be any difference in disk space usage whether you uninstall and reinstall or just leave it installed during the upgrade.

Longer answer - My understanding is that there is essentially no difference between WSL2 running on Windows Home vs. Windows Professional.  What you may be thinking of is that Windows Pro has the ability to run Hyper-V as an optional feature, whereas Home does not.  However, WSL2 capability is provided under all SKUs as the same Windows Optional Feature ("VirtualMachinePlatform").  So you won't be getting rid of that component (and thus reclaiming that space) if that's what you are thinking.

Enabling the optional Hyper-V feature under Pro will give you tools which will allow you to manage the Hyper-V VM that WSL2 is running on, but it's not automatically installed/enabled when upgrading to Pro.  And it doesn't replace the WSL2 Virtual Machine Platform.

If you want to, however, you can always export the filesystem from WSL2 (`wsl --export`, see `wsl --help` for arguments), unregister the WSL2 instance (`wsl --unregister <distro>`, and then reimport it after upgrading (`wsl --import`).